# Вывод картинок в HTML форму с помощью PHP

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. 
Делаю следующее:

```
$dir = "images/";
$odir = opendir($dir);

while ($file = readdir($odir))
{
    $word = explode("#", $file);
$big = $dir."big#".$word[1];
$small = $dir."small#".$word[1];

    echo "<a href=".$big." target=_blank><img src=".$small." hspace=30px vspace=20px></img></a>";
}

closedir($odir);
```

для того, чтобы вывести картинки на страницу. картинки не выводятся. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибаюсь?

Comment: А вы пробовали смотреть, куда указывают ваши ссылки?
Любой утилитой, например firebug, посмотрите что у вас выходит в конечном счете.

Comment: я пробовал вот так: echo $big; выводит правильный путь.

Comment: Посмотрите html код страницы - это может помочь. И, кстати, закрывающий тег img не нужен.

Comment: @SterSwift, я немного не врублюсь, что вы хотите сделать. Точнее я понимаю концепцию, а вот алгоритм мне немного не понятен.

Comment: есть папка /images с большими и маленькими картинками. маленькие нужно отображать на странице, большие по нажатию. у меня следующий ход мыслей: разбиваю explode-ом каждое имя файла, после добавляю приставку в виде small# или big# и вывожу. коряво? а как лучше?

Comment: картинки в папке называются small#img1.jpg, big#img2.jpg и тд..

Comment: Просто в таком случае у вас будет N - ссылок для каждого файла. А вам нужно N/2 так как файлы и большие и маленькие в одной директории.
Кроме того, вы не проверяете файл ".." который идет первым.

Comment: а как проверить файл ".."? и я собираюсь держать маленькие и большие в разных директориях. правильно ли это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот вам ответ:

```
<?php 
$dir = "./images/";
$odir = opendir($dir);

while ($file = readdir($odir))
{
    if($file == ".." || $file == ".")
    continue;
    $word = explode("-", $file);
    $big = $dir."big-".$word[1];
    $small = $dir."small-".$word[1];

    echo "<a href=\"".$big."\" target=_blank><img src=\"".$small."\" hspace=30px vspace=20px></a>";
}

closedir($odir);
```

Не любит браузер символ "#". Когда меняешь на "-", все работает.
Кроме того, вам надо как-то теперь придумать, что делать с большими и маленькими картинками, иначе будет у вас по две штуки.
Например:

```
...
$word = explode("-", $file);
if($word[0] == "small")
   continue;
...
```

Вот как-то так навскидку я бы сделал.